# Test tweet post with twitter API

Tags: api, twitter

I'm working on a twitter integration that will post a tweet. I would like to test this integration without posting a live tweet to the account. I can't find any information on how to do this.

For clarity, I'm using `https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets POST` https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/manage-tweets/api-reference/post-tweets

Comment: Use a different private account, then when deploying put in the "live" account?

Comment: @sntrenter This seems like a reasonable approach, albeit without a straight forward way to authorize the additional access if the app doesn't have a gui. I was hoping there was a more "official" way, seeing as their ads and search apis have a legitimate sandbox.

Comment: After further investigation it looks like the [3-legged oauth flow with PIN](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/obtaining-user-access-tokens) won't work with the v2 api, as the v2 api requires oauth 2 per the docs. I'll either have to build a separate UI to get the test account oauth 2 bearer token, or use the v1 twitter api so I can just run a script to get the pin.